# How to upload a file and process it with SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml

I'm using this form:

```
<form action="abc.php" method="post" name="fname">
   <input type="file" name="up" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

that's handled by this PHP:

```
$par = $_POST['up'];
$xml = @simplexml_load_file(file_get_contents($par));
$xml = $xml->getName();
echo $xml;
```

and it's giving me this error message: `unable to load external entity`. How can I fix this?

Comment: That's not `XML` that's `HTML`...

Answer (score 1):

- You need the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in your `form` to accept a file:

  ```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="abc.php" method="post" name="fname">
  ```
- Files go into `$_FILES`, not into `$_POST`, so your `$par` initialization should be:

  ```
  $par = $_FILES['up'];
  ```
- And what Dj Boris said is on the right track, your call to `simplexml_load_file` should be:

  ```
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($par['tmp_name']);
  ```

Comment: listen me what i have to do.
i have to take a file of XML then take a user defined tag and their node value and store into db...would you like to help me in this regard

Comment: @AliMohsin You can put the name of the tag into a variable and use the variable on a SimpleXMLElement e.g. `$xml->$userTagName` to get the value. You should post that as a separate question. It would be confusing to other users to try and answer that above and not helpful to other users to have the answer just in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers are correct. If you pass `simplexml_load_file()` `$_FILES['index']` you will get an error saying the following:

> simplexml_load_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given

The solution is to pass it the temporary file name located inside the `$_FILES` array.

Solution:

```
$svg = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['up']['tmp_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are writing:

```
simplexml_load_file(file_get_contents($par));
```

But I think, it should be

```
simplexml_load_file($par);
```

According to http://php.net/manual/de/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Comment: u write
but i have to print an XML file line by line i can't do so